# Java сравнение string ответа

Tags: java, строки

Данная программа является игрой "Рулетка", игрок должен сделать ставку на красное или на черное, парное или не парное, Проблема вот в чем, игрок всегда выигрывает, если напишет string = "Красное"Черное""Парное"Непарное",например игрок написал что ставит на Красное, а выпало черное, но игрок все равно выиграл, я понимаю в чем причина но не могу это ошибку исправить потому что не знаю как, знаком с java 3 дня.
Проблема в этом блоке кода:

```
if (stavka.equals("Красное")) {
    System.out.println("Ставка сыграла, вы победили!Выиграшь составляет:" + summa * 2);
} else if (stavka.equals("Черное")) {
    System.out.println("Ставка сыграла, вы победили!Выиграшь составляет:" + summa * 2);
} else if (stavka.equals("Не четное")) {
    System.out.println("Ставка сыграла, вы победили!Выиграшь составляет:" + summa * 2);
} else if (stavka.equals("Четное")) {
    System.out.println("Ставка сыграла, вы победили!Выиграшь составляет:" + summa * 2);
} else
```

Игрок выигрывает если напишет любой вариант из выше перечисленных, а надо сделать так что бы он выигрывал только если его ставка совпадет с тем что выпало.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Bender {

static boolean playAgain = true;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    while (playAgain) {
        Game();
    }
}

public static void Game() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int summa;
    String stavka;
    System.out.println("Здравствуйте в рулетке, на что ставите?Красное или Черное?Парное или не Парное?");
    stavka = scanner.next();

    System.out.println("Какую сумму ставите?");
    summa = scanner.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        int b;
        String[] colour = {"Черное.", "Красное."};
        Random random = new Random();
        Random random1 = new Random();
        int select = random.nextInt(colour.length);
        b = (random1.nextInt(36));
        if (b == 0) {
            System.out.print("");
        } else if ((b & 1) == 0) {
            System.out.print(" Выпало четное" + " ");
        } else {
            System.out.print("Выпало нечетное" + " ");
        }
        System.out.println(b + " " + colour[select]);
    }
    if (stavka.equals("Красное")) {
        System.out.println("Ставка сыграла, вы победили!Выиграшь составляет:" + summa * 2);
    } else if (stavka.equals("Черное")) {
        System.out.println("Ставка сыграла, вы победили!Выиграшь составляет:" + summa * 2);
    } else if (stavka.equals("Не четное")) {
        System.out.println("Ставка сыграла, вы победили!Выиграшь составляет:" + summa * 2);
    } else if (stavka.equals("Четное")) {
        System.out.println("Ставка сыграла, вы победили!Выиграшь составляет:" + summa * 2);
    } else


    playAgain = false;
    System.out.println("Вы проиграли,делаем ставку еще раз?");
    String otvet;
    otvet = scanner.next();
    if (otvet.equals("Да")) {
        System.out.println("Продолжаем!");
        playAgain = true;
    }
    if (otvet.equals("Нет")) {
        System.out.println("Жаль(До Встречи!");
    }

}

}
```

Comment: А где вы вообще сравниваете с тем что выпало?

Comment: Используйте логический оператор И `&&`: `stavka.equals("Чётное") && (b&1==0)`

Answer (score 1):

Собирался разместить полный вариант в прошлом вопросе, но раз появился новый вопрос, то напишу здесь.

1. Для корректного сравнения нужно учитывать кодировку данных, идущих из `System.in`. В своём примере я использовал *CP866* для работы из консоли Windows.
2. Сравнивать ставку `stavka` нужно с `colour[select]` (`colors[colorIndex]` в моём коде) и с `"Четное"` и `"Нечетное"` в зависимости от значения `b` (`number`). Сравнить на четность можно по аналогии с цветами, создав массив с чет/нечет (`parity`).
3. Видимо, нужно ещё сравнивать `stavka` с `b` (если можно поставить на конкретное число), но этого в исходном коде нет.

Полный код:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String[] colors = { "Черное", "Красное" };
    String[] parity = { "Четное", "Нечетное" };
    Random random = new Random();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in, "CP866");
    boolean isPlaying = true;
    while (isPlaying)
    {
        System.out.println("Сделайте вашу ставку. Вы можете поставить на Красное или Черное, на Четное или Нечетное.");
        String stavka = scanner.next();
        System.out.println("Какую сумму ставите?");
        int summa = scanner.nextInt();
        int colorIndex = random.nextInt(colors.length);
        int number = random.nextInt(36);
        System.out.println("Выпало " + parity[number % 2] + " " + number + " " + colors[colorIndex]);
        if (stavka.equals(colors[colorIndex]) || stavka.equals(parity[number % 2]))
        {
            System.out.println("Ставка сыграла, вы победили! Выигрыш составляет: " + summa * 2);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Вы проиграли");
        }
        System.out.println("Делаем ставку еще раз?");
        String otvet = scanner.next();
        if (otvet.equals("Да"))
        {
            System.out.println("Продолжаем!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Жаль. До встречи!");
            isPlaying = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Проверка на правильность значения `stavka` происходит в этой строке:

```
if (stavka.equals(colors[colorIndex]) || stavka.equals(parity[number % 2]))
```

Comment: В любом случаи ставка не правильная, даже если ставлю черное и выпадает черное, все равно пишет ставка не сыграна(

Comment: @Roman определитесь с кодировкой, используемой в консоли, из которой вы запускаете приложение. Возможно, вместо `CP866` вам нужно использовать `Windows-1251` или `UTF-8`. Сам код работает правильно (если, конечно, писать в консоли строго так, как задано, то есть `Черное`, а не `черное`).

Comment: Спасибо помогло!Все заработало как надо.Если не сложно, обьясните пожалуйста как кодировка повлияла на работу программы, почему после того как я поменял CP866 на utf-8 Все заработало?

Comment: @Roman на здоровье. Потому что в каждой консоли используется та или иная кодировка. Где-то одна, где-то - другая. В консоли Windows, например, идёт `CP866`. В консоли NetBeans - `Windows-1251`. У вас в какой-то другой консоли вообще `UTF-8`. Тут уж кто (из создателей консолей) на что горазд. Приходится подстраиваться под конкретную консоль для корректной обработки введённых русских букв. И если ответ вас устраивает, то не забудьте отметить его как подходящий (галочка слева от ответа).